# Illustrator objects get darker and solid (not lighter and opaque) when reducing opacity

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Think I'm going mad :/

I have an Illustrator file open that I repeatedly use to create web UI designs - open the file, save as new, delete the previous contents, start with the grid and artboards. Currently, when I reduce the opacity of a Normal blend mode object on a white background, the object becomes darker, not lighter, and it remains solid rather than becoming transparent. I have a second file open (for sanity) and opacity works as it should. Can anyone shed light on why this might be please?

I've grabbed an example below. Does anyone know how to fix this issue please?

For what it's worth I've been using Illustrator 15+ years.

Comment: you outside of an artboard?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was caused by blank transparency % entry on the entire layer. Silly me.